# SQL Server Create View from Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables in a SQL Server database that keeps track of a social network. First is the friends table which looks like

```
userId | friendId | acceptDate
==============================
   1   |     8    | 2018-01-20
   8   |     12   | 2017-11-20
   12  |     1    | 2017-12-18
```

So each pair is a uniqe combination, and the order is just determined by which user initiated the connection.

The second table is a table with user information

```
userId | name | email | ...
   1   | John  | john@example.com  | ...
   2   | Bill  | bill@example.com  | ...
   3   | Cathy | cathy@example.com | ...
```

I want to create a view where I can easily grab the data I need for a particular user's friends with minimal server side processing. So essentially I want to create a View where the data would look like:

```
userId | friendID | friendName | friendEmail | acceptDate | ....
   1   |     8    |  8's Name  |  8's Email  | 2018-01-20 |...
   1   |    12    |  12's Name |  12's Email | 2017-12-18 |...
   8   |    12    |  12's Name |  12's Email | 2017-11-20 |...
   8   |     1    |  1's Name  |  1's Email  | 2018-01-20 |...
  12   |     1    |  1's Name  |  1's Email  | 2017-12-18 |...
  12   |     8    |  8's Name  |  8's Email  | 2017-11-20 |...
```

Basically, it will create two rows from each friendship pair that exists in the friends table (one in the existing order, and one flipped), and will join the friend's information from the user table.  This way, I can simply query the view to find me all of a specific user's friends, and it'll return the rows of only that user's friends with their info and I won't have to do any processing to sort things out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your table design is a bit less than optimal but it can work. What have you tried? Seems to me you need to use a left join on both userID or friendID to your other table.

Comment: Well maybe not a left join since that would return users that have no friends, which isn't the desired result in the question.

Comment: @TabAlleman true enough. The reason this query is so difficult is because the data structure is not well designed. When you design your data correctly it is easy to retrieve information. But when your design is not good it is a pain to work with.

Comment: Thank you all so much for helping me out! How should this database have been designed to make things easier? I'd love to hear any suggestions you all have and see if I can do anything about it. @SeanLange

Comment: I come more from a programming background so structuring SQL queries takes a bit of a different mindset from processing data in python or php.  I had tried a few types of joins, but the answer below using the inner join with the 'on'/'or' part seems to have done the trick. I tried to be as clear as possible with my post and not sure why I got the downvotes there, but any tips on that would be useful for future posts. Thanks again!

Comment: The downvote wasn't from me but your desired output does not seem to match the sample data provided. For example you have no userid = 12 in your sample but it is in the output. Ideally you would post create table statements and insert statements for sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way this could be done with JOINs:

```
SELECT u.UserID, fi.UserID AS FriendID, fi.Name, fi.email, f.acceptdate
FROM UserInfo u
INNER JOIN Friends f
  ON u.UserID=f.UserID
  OR u.UserID=f.FriendID
INNER JOIN UserInfo fi
  ON (fi.UserID=f.UserID AND u.UserID=f.FriendID)
  OR (fi.UserID=f.FriendID AND u.UserID=f.UserID)
ORDER BY u.UserID, fi.UserID
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how I 'feel' about 4 of us answering this question with the illogical design rather than explaining in detail the flaws of the design and showing the op the correct way to model this ...

Comment: I think of it as an exercise in overcoming bad designs.   Some developers aren't given the option of being able to redefine the database design.   However, if at least one answer showed a better design for the same objective, it would certainly add value to the site.

Comment: Thank you all so much for helping me out! How should this database have been designed to make things easier?  I'd love to hear any suggestions you all have and see if I can do anything about it.  @TabAlleman

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to switch all the data in the first two columns you are going to need to double up the amount data. This is probably easiest using a UNION ALL. Something like this should be pretty close.

```
select *
from
(
    select UserID
        , FriendID
        , FriendName = sot.name
    from SomeTable st
    join SomeOtherTable sot on sot.UserID = st.UserID

    UNION ALL

    select FriendID
        , UserID
        , FriendName = sot.name
    from SomeTable st
    join SomeOtherTable sot on sot.UserID = st.FriendID
) x
order by x.UserID
    , x.FriendID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Friends I accepted 
select userid, f.userId friendID, f.name friendName, f.email friendEmail, friends.acceptDate
from users inner join friends on users.userId = friends.userId inner join users f on friends.friendId = f.Userid

union all
-- friends who accepted me. 
select userid, f.userId friendID, f.name friendName, f.email friendEmail, friends.acceptDate
from users inner join friends on users.userId = friends.friendID inner join users f on friends.userid = f.Userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

Edit, I've added the email from the userID, and added the `union all` to support the ops heart, happy v-day.

```
declare @user as table (
    userID       int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
,   Name_        nvarchar(255) not null
,   EmailAddress nvarchar(255) not null
);

declare @duo as table (
    duoID   int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered 
,   userID  int not null
,   loserID int not null
,   LoveDate date not null
);

insert into @user (name_, EmailAddress)

select 'bob', 'bob@example.com' union all
select 'tom', 'tom@example.com' union all
select 'nick', 'nick@example.com' union all
select 'Random', 'awesomesauce@example.com';

insert into @duo (userid, loserid, LoveDate)
select 1, 2, '2018-01-14' union all
select 1, 3, '2018-02-14' union all
select 1, 4, '2018-01-15' union all
select 2, 3, '2018-01-14' union all
select 2, 4, '2018-01-18' union all
select 3, 4, '2018-01-13';


select a.UserID
     , a.Name_ Person
     , a.EmailAddress
     , c.userID LoserID
     , c.Name_ Loser
     , c.EmailAddress 'Loser''s Email'
     , b.LoveDate
  from @user a
  join @duo b
    on a.userid = b.userid
  join @user c
    on b.loserid = c.userid

union all

select c.userID 
     , c.Name_ Person
     , c.EmailAddress
     , a.UserID LoserID
     , a.Name_ Loser
     , a.EmailAddress 'Loser''s Email'
     , b.LoveDate
  from @user a
  join @duo b
    on a.userid = b.userid
  join @user c
    on b.loserid = c.userid
```